# Sort the information in a different file excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a problem with my macro and I would like to know if someone could help me.
I am doing a macro in a file, and that macro will go accessing other file and sort the information existing there. Until now I have the following code:

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim xl As New Application
    Dim xlw As Workbook
    Dim xls As Worksheet

    a = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\A.csv"
    On Error GoTo bm:
    Set xlw = xl.Workbooks.Open(a)
    Set xls = xlw.Sheets(1)


'    Windows(a).Activate
    a = xls.Name
    Columns("C:C").Select
    xlw.Worksheets(a).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    xlw.Worksheets(a).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2"), SortOn _
        :=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With xlw.Worksheets(a).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:K297594")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

bm:
    xlw.Saved = True
    xlw.Close True
    xl.Quit
    Set xls = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

When put it running , when it reaches the instruction ".SetRange Range("A2:K297594")" it gives "Run-time error 5" and I don't understand why. So could anyone explain me how resolve this or why is giving this error?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range is not referenced and Excel doesNOT know of which sheet you are talking about, it should be `.SetRange xlw.Worksheets(a).Range("A2:K297594")` :

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim xl As New Application
    Dim xlw As Workbook
    Dim xls As Worksheet

    a = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\A.csv"
    On Error GoTo bm:
    Set xlw = xl.Workbooks.Open(a, Local:=True)
    Set xls = xlw.Sheets(1)


'    Windows(a).Activate
    a = xls.Name
    Columns("C:C").Select
    xlw.Worksheets(a).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    xlw.Worksheets(a).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=xlw.Worksheets(a).Range("C2"), SortOn _
        :=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With xlw.Worksheets(a).Sort
        .SetRange xlw.Worksheets(a).Range("A2:K297594")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

bm:
    xlw.Save
    xlw.Close True
    xl.Quit
    Set xls = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Would suggest declaring and not reusing variable `a`.

Comment: virtually same answer at same time, but range `Range("C2")` is still unqualified in your answer

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : thx for pointing it out, I'll correct this right away! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, at least the error not occur anymore. Still with the problem that can't sort but that is my fault, I just now realized that I'm working with a csv file and they just have one column making impossible make the sort that I want to do. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @OutOfMemory : But you can! Try the edit and notice the `Local:=True` argument in the `Open` statement, it should open the CSV and separate the columns! ;)

Comment: @R3uK Oh, I didn't notice it and didn't know that, but thanks for the explanation.
But I have another question, is the save file statement correct? I never use this and I see different ways of save the file in some websites. I'm asking this because in the end of running the macro, the file stay without changes, without be in order.

Comment: @OutOfMemory : Personally, I'd use `xlw.Save` which is easy to remember and auto complete when you declared variable as workbook! is everything else ok?

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify all your workbook, worksheet and range references, especially since you are running a macro against another workbook from where the macro runs.

You were really almost there (99%). This will clean it up for you:

```
    Dim wName as String 'since you already use a to get the file name
    wName = xls.Name

    With xlw.Worksheets(wName).Sort

        With .SortFields

            .Clear
            'note . (period) in front of range and I am pretty sure you need to set the 
             'whole range reference ... hence the C297597 ... but maybe just C2 is enough
            .Add Key:=.Range("C2:C297594"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        End With

        'note . (period) in front of range
        .SetRange .Range("A2:K297594")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With
```

Comment: The program don't run until the end but the problem could be the same thing that i refer in the other answer, I just realized now that I'm working with csv files and they just have one column. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @OutOfMemory - does the CSV truly have only 1 column? or is everything listed in one column? If it's the latter, you can do a [TextToColumns](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html) and then sort.

Comment: The file have 5 columns, but in another macro that I have when goes counting the number of columns, it just counted one column that possess all the info of the line.

Comment: exactly, so you can use `TextToColumns` to delimit the data into columns as I have linked to in my previous line.

Comment: Ok, but when I open the file it is already each information in separate cells correctly, the problem is when I going read. So maybe I' not understand well the work of Text To Columns but it seems it's not that its need

Comment: @OutOfMemory - *separate cells* - means, columns or rows?

Comment: Separate cells means both, each info is in the right line and column.